sklearn importing standard scaler
I imported standardscaler for a code:
from sklearn.preprocessing import standardscaler

It shows like
cannot import name 'standardscaler' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'

How to solve the error?

Names in Python are case-sensitive.
Try:
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


it worked thank you sir!!

Please do not answer questions that are essentially due to typos; leave a comment and vote to close them as such instead.

@desertnaut Got it. What is the right way here, do I flag with "In need of moderator intervention" or is there a more specific action?

There should be a more specific action related to "flag as off-topic/needing improvement", or something (cannot see the options available to you as different things apply for different reputation levels).
